# Edit links in place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this javascript to edit text in place: http://josephscott.org/code/javascript/jquery-edit-in-place now I need to edit links as well. But when I click on link instead of just making it editable I'm redirected to the link address. How can I change it so that if double click a link just make it editable and don't redirect anywhere?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You mean you want to follow the link on `click` and edit it on `doubleclick` ? This is not possible because a double-click also always issues a click event.

Comment: Yes, that's possible! http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/ this plugin does so but my website doesn't work on wordpress...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [`dblclick`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event and the [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method

```
  $('a_selector').eip( "save.php", {
    form_type: "textarea"
} );

$('a_selector').dblclick(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

***update***
After toying around with  the plugin a little..

I believe it natively allows to set the event which starts the edit..

```
$('a').eip( 'save.php', {
        form_type  : 'textarea',
        edit_event : 'dblclick'
    } );
```

but i am not sure they correctly handle the case where the target element is a link, as i do not see in their code any attempt to stop the default behaviour ..

Maybe you could modify the source code and add it yourself ..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to override the default link behavior, then trigger the edit-in-place code.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    //whatever you have to call to make it editable
    return false; //prevent the link from being followed
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine! How should I modify the code to enter the link as before if I click it only once?

Comment: I would check out Gaby's answer at this point, he seems to know a lot more about the plugin in question.

Answer (score 0):

Return false from your event handler, or with jQuery use `e.preventDefault()` in the handler, where e is the event object.